# Batch file for loop with tokens over multiple lines

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to take the hotfixes output from systeminfo:

```
Hotfix(s):                 9 Hotfix(s) Installed.
                           [01]: KB3124262
                           [02]: KB3135173
                           [03]: KB3136561
                           [04]: KB3139907
                           [05]: KB3140741
                           [06]: KB3140743
                           [07]: KB3140768
                           [08]: KB3154132
                           [09]: KB3147458
```

However, I only want the KB####### part. The following:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
for /F "tokens=2" %%a IN ('find "KB" hotfix.txt') do (
  set Hot=%%~a
  echo %Hot%
)
```

Gave me this output:

```
[++Hotfix(s) Installed]

KB3147458 echo KB3147458
KB3147458 echo KB3147458
KB3147458 echo KB3147458
KB3147458 echo KB3147458
KB3147458 echo KB3147458
KB3147458 echo KB3147458
KB3147458 echo KB3147458
KB3147458 echo KB3147458
KB3147458 echo KB3147458
KB3147458 echo KB3147458
```

Which is the same line over and over, but is the right amount of lines from what is above. Been going at this for too long and feel I am shooting around the target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you already have [enabled delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) but you need to access the variabled with `!` instead of `%`:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
for /F "tokens=2" %%a IN ('find "KB" hotfix.txt') do (
  set Hot=%%~a
  echo !Hot!
)
```

Comment: That did it, haha. Had not came across the ! yet.

`[++Hotfix(s) Installed]

HOTFIX.TXT
KB3124262
KB3135173
KB3136561
KB3139907
KB3140741
KB3140743
KB3140768
KB3154132
KB3147458`

Do have hotfix.txt at the beginning now though, which is unexpected.

Comment: @Josh - may it will be easier to list hotfixes with `wmic qfe get HotFixID`

Comment: True, however I am writing this script so anyone could use it despite level of access. WMIC isn't always accessible to your account permissions, or isn't installed; XP SP1 and prior.

Comment: Got the hotfix.txt line removed. Thanks for the help :)